# xslt template to devide item in column

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a problem with dividing elements in columns. I have a list of anchors which i have to show in columns and number of columns is configurable

say we have below

```
<links>
<link>one</link>
<link>two</link>
<link>three</link>
<link>four</link>
<link>five</link>
<link>six</link>
<link>seven</link>
<link>eight</link>
<link>nine</link>
<link>ten</link>
<link>eleven</link>
<link>twelve</link>
<link>thirteen</link>
</links>
```

Requirement is to show these links in ordered list and result should be as below
if number of column is 3

1. one             6. six          10. ten
2. two             7. seven     11. eleven
3. three       8. eight       12. twelve
4. four            9. nine         13. thirteen
5. five

if number of column is 4

1. one     5. five     8. eight         11. eleven
2. two           6. six           9. nine          12. twelve
3. three     7. seven     10. ten          13. thirteen
4. four

I have one logic which require loop, but want more systematic solution. Can only use xslt 1.0.

Logic for my solution is

if I have to divide in 3 columns then

Mod= totalItem Mod Total_No_Columns;
quotient= floor(totalItem div Total_No_Columns);
for(i=1 to 3 )
{

call template GenerateOL with param (i, Mod, total items, quotient)
}

template code
GenerateOL
{

  Var addFactor = maximum((i-1), Mod)
  var startPosition=(quotient(i-1)+1 + addFactor);
  var endPosition=addFactor+quotient*i + (i>=mod)?1:0;
  call link teplate with position startPosition to end Position.

}

Comment: cant go 1,2,3<br>4,5,6<br>7,8,9 ?

Comment: No. I have to go like <ol> 1, 2,3,4</ol> <ol> 5,6,7</ol><ol> 8,9,10</ol>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="pNumCols" select="3"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vCount" select="count(/*/*)"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vRemainder"
      select="$vCount mod $pNumCols"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vPerCol" select="floor($vCount div $pNumCols)"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <table border="1">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(position() > ceiling($vCount div $pNumCols))]"/>
     </table>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="link">
  <xsl:variable name="vCurrentItem" select="."/>
  <xsl:variable name="vRow" select="position()"/>
  <tr>
    <xsl:for-each select=
     "(//node()|//namespace::*)[not(position() > $pNumCols)]">

     <xsl:variable name="vColNo" select="position()"/>
       <xsl:apply-templates mode="inGroup" select=
        "$vCurrentItem/../*
             [position() = ($vColNo -1)*$vPerCol+ $vRemainder
             - ($vRemainder - $vColNo +1)*not($vColNo > $vRemainder)+ $vRow
             ]
             [not($vRow > $vPerCol and $vColNo > $vRemainder)]"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </tr>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="link" mode="inGroup">
  <td><xsl:number count="link"/>. <xsl:copy-of select="text()"/></td>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<links>
    <link>one</link>
    <link>two</link>
    <link>three</link>
    <link>four</link>
    <link>five</link>
    <link>six</link>
    <link>seven</link>
    <link>eight</link>
    <link>nine</link>
    <link>ten</link>
    <link>eleven</link>
    <link>twelve</link>
    <link>thirteen</link>
</links>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td>1. one</td>
      <td>6. six</td>
      <td>10. ten</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>2. two</td>
      <td>7. seven</td>
      <td>11. eleven</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>3. three</td>
      <td>8. eight</td>
      <td>12. twelve</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>4. four</td>
      <td>9. nine</td>
      <td>13. thirteen</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>5. five</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

**If we specify `$pNumCols` as 4, the transformation again produces the correct result:**

```
<table border="1">
   <tr>
      <td>1. one</td>
      <td>5. five</td>
      <td>8. eight</td>
      <td>11. eleven</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>2. two</td>
      <td>6. six</td>
      <td>9. nine</td>
      <td>12. twelve</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>3. three</td>
      <td>7. seven</td>
      <td>10. ten</td>
      <td>13. thirteen</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>4. four</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Dimitre. This look great and solve my problem. However it has two issues which are bothering me<br> 1. I don't want to write index by myself. <br> 2. Instead of grouping it in rows, I want to group in <ol> and group like <ol><li>1</li><li>2</li></ol> <br> to make css easy. I will wait for 1 more day and if no body answered this question, will accept your answer

Comment: @gauravhanda, This is a new requirement that comes in a comment that is difficult to read, two days after your question has been asked and completely answered. It isn't ethical to add unannounced requirements so late after the question has been asked and answered. Please, ask *a new question* for your new requirements. Your original/current question has been answered completely -- please, accept this answer.

Comment: I guess you are right. I forgot to mention my this requirement in my question and that is my fault. You answered current requirement and given acceptable answer.

Comment: @gauravhanda, If the conversion from rows to columns was easy, I would have done this -- NP. However, it requires very different algorithm and calculations. When you ask the new questions let me know, and I'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

try this logic

if you have 10 links and you have to show them in 3 columns, then first divide them
10 divided by 3 = 3.33
took ceiling of your result which is 4
so take a=4
Now on each item try to generate OL only if its Position() mod 4 = 1.

Comment: Could you plesae add a fiddle. Your answer is not very clear here.

Comment: I tried your approach but it is not giving me desired result. it is giving me 1-5 in first column, 6-10 in second and 11-13 in third. However I want 1-5 in first, 6-9 in second and 10-13 in third column.